# How to inject multiple mocks of the same interface

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, mocking, mockito

The Java class (called `ServiceCaller`) I wish to test has this:

```
@Autowired @Qualifier(value="serviceA")
SomeService serviceA;

@Autowired @Qualifier(value="serviceB")
SomeService serviceB;
```

(there's a `doWork()` method that will check a condition and call either A or B).

How do I inject a mock of each service into the appropriate variable?

My [Junit](http://junit.org/) has this:

```
@InjectMocks ServiceCaller classUnderTest = new ServiceCaller();

@Mock SomeService mockServiceA;
@Mock SomeService mockServiceB;
```

Yet when I run my tests to check that service A/B called under the correct condition, I get null pointers as the mock hasn't been injected.

Obviously its because of multiple dependencies on the same interface (`SomeService`). Is there a way to specify the qualifier when declaring the mock service? Or do I need to have setters for the dependencies and set the old fashioned way?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It should be enough to name your mocks serviceA and serviceB. From Mockito [documentation](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/InjectMocks.html):

> Property setter injection; mocks will first be resolved by type, then,
>   if there is several property of the same type, by the match of the
>   property name and the mock name.

In your example:

```
@InjectMocks ServiceCaller classUnderTest;

@Mock SomeService serviceA;
@Mock SomeService serviceB;
```

Note that it is not necessary to manually create class instance when using @InjectMocks.

Nevertheless I personally prefer injecting dependencies using constructor. It makes it easier to inject mocks in tests (just call a constructor with your mocks - without reflections tools or `@InjectMocks` (which is useful, but hides some aspects)). In addition using [TDD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) it is clearly visible what dependencies are needed for the tested class and also IDE can generate your constructor stubs.

Spring Framework completely supports constructor injection:

```
@Bean
public class ServiceCaller {
    private final SomeService serviceA;
    private final SomeService serviceB;

    @Autowired
    public ServiceCaller(@Qualifier("serviceA") SomeService serviceA,
                         @Qualifier("serviceB") SomeService serviceB) { ... }

    ...
}
```

This code can be tested with:

```
@Mock SomeService serviceA;
@Mock SomeService serviceB;

//in a setup or test method
ServiceCaller classUnderTest = new ServiceCaller(serviceA, serviceB);
```

Comment: Brilliant! Hoped it would be something as simple as that and it works. Thanks Szpak!!!

Comment: In you last line of code you can write:
@InjectMocks ServiceCaller classUnderTest;

Comment: Yes, but please read the text in the middle of my answer to get know why I usually prefer to call a constructor in tests explicitly.

Comment: Very good and correct answer! I was hoping that by naming the `@Mock(name="nameMatchingQualifier")` they would automatically match the `@Qualifier` in constrcutor therefore using `@InjectMocks `rather than calling the constructor manually from the test.

Comment: Well @ACV, `@Qualifier` is a Spring-specific annotation, so it would have to be implemented using a reflection. `InjectMocks` in Mockito already is quite complicated (and occasionally surprising for newcomers - e.g. it can skip a constructor injection assuming a new constructor argument is added and switch to a field injection, leaving the new field not set - `null`). Therefore, you can create a ticket for that in Mockito, but the team would be probably reluctant to implement that.

Answer (score 17):

you can use "name" property to define your instance like this:

```
@Mock(name="serviceA") SomeService serviceA;
@Mock(name="serviceB") SomeService serviceB;
```

Comment: Can you supply any further details to explain how your answer adds any value that the accepted answer doesn't already provide?

Comment: If you are autowiring on a field, instead of the constructor (although this is bad practice), this is the only way to go

Answer (score 5):

When you have same type dependencies mockito stops injecting the depedencies due to properties of same types. To resolve this with reference to @osiris256 in the following way:

```
class ServiceLayer{

   @Autowired
   @Qualifier("bean1")
   private InterfaceA typeA;  

   @Autowired
   @Qualifier("bean2")
   private InterfaceA typeB;  

}
```

Your test class should be:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)    
class ServiceLayerTest{

  @Mock(name = "typeA")
  private InterfaceA typeA;  

  @Mock(name = "typeB")
  private InterfaceA typeB;  

  @InjectMocks
  ServiceLayer serviceLayer;

  @Before
  public void initialiseBeforeTest(){
     MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
  }

  // here goes your test 
  @Test
   public void test(){
     // use your when then .....
  }
}
```

Note: if you are using SpringRunner and use @MockBean this will not work,
you have to replace with @Mock(name="") with reference to @osiris256.

Comment: Using `@MockBean(name = "typeA")` worked for me in a test case annotated with `@SpringBootTest`.