# Mockito - Mock not being injected for one of the testcases

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I have a jsf spring application and using *mockito* for my unit test. I keep getting `NullPointerException` when i run my `junit` test in `iEmployeeService` mocking. There are not `Exception` for `iSecurityLoginService`.

Method to be mocked

```
@Autowired
IEmployeeService iEmployeeService;
@Autowired
ISecurityLoginService iSecurityLoginService;
public void addEvent() {

    entityEventsCreate.setTitle(entityEventsCreate.getTitle());
    entityEventsCreate.setModifiedBy(iSecurityLoginService
                .findLoggedInUserId());

    int eventId = iEmployeeService.addEmployeeTimeOff(entityEventsCreate);
}
```

My JUnit test is annotated with `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)`

```
@Mock
ISecurityLoginService iSecurityLoginService;

@Mock
IEmployeeService iEmployeeService;

@InjectMocks
ServiceCalendarViewBean serviceCalendarViewBean  = new ServiceCalendarViewBean();

@Before public void initMocks() {
           MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

@Test
public void testSaveEvent() {
    Mockito.when(iSecurityLoginService.findLoggedInUserId()).thenReturn(1);
    serviceCalendarViewBean.getEntityEventsCreate().setTitle("Junit Event Testing");

    Mockito.when(iSecurityLoginService.findLoggedInUserId()).thenReturn(1);
    Mockito.when(iEmployeeService.addEmployeeTimeOff(Mockito.any(Events.class))).thenReturn(2);

    serviceCalendarViewBean.addEvent();
}
```

Comment: Adding the stack trace would be welcome. Also where is created `entityEventsCreate` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved the problem..In my spring bean, i had 2 objects for the same service interface. so the mock was being set for the first interface object.

Ex: in my bean i had,

```
@Autowired
IEmployeeService employeeService;
@Autowired
IEmployeeService iEmployeeService;
```

So the mock create for the IEmployeeservice interfaces was being inject for the first service object irrelevant for their names.

```
@Mock
IEmployeeService iEmployeeService;
```

ie, the mock object 'iEmployeeService' was injected to beans 'employeeService' .

Thank you for all those who helped..:)

Comment: So this is the problem you had, but could you kindly post how you solved your problem, please?
EDIT: I found an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21054057/how-to-inject-multiple-mocks-of-the-same-interface

Answer (score 10):

**Not related to the question, but useful to know !**

If the test is annotated with `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` then `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);` is not necessary (it may even cause issues when injecting), the mockito runner performs injection and additional stuffs to validate mocks.

Also having both mock init mechanisms may cause trouble with injection and stubbing, this is due to the way the lifecyle of JUnit test and how mockito unit-integration code is used :

1. The runner will create mocks and inject those mocks in the test object.
2. Then the `@Before` methods kicks in and recreate new mocks, and may not perform injection as the object is already initialized.

Comment: It's maybe not related, but this was the cause of the error in my case (it seemed like mockito was ignoring the Mockito.when(xxx).thenReturn(yyy)). Deleting MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this); solved it. Thank you for sharing.

Answer (score 4):

Try to add this

```
@Before
public void initMocks() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Bono I recommend you read this MSE post: [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370)

Comment: Ironically, what solved the problem for me was to remove this initMocks() call.  I mixed @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class) and MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this) and that causes injections to fail.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and after few researches, I found that it looks like the `@InjectMocks` were not working and failing silently without injecting the `@AutoWired` *private objects*,

**Solution :** Change the design by making the dependencies visible through constructor,

```
IEmployeeService iEmployeeService;
ISecurityLoginService iSecurityLoginService;

@Autowired
public ServiceCalendarViewBean(final IEmployeeService iEmployeeService,
                final ISecurityLoginService iSecurityLoginService){
    this.iEmployeeService=iEmployeeService;
    this.iSecurityLoginService=iSecurityLoginService;
}
```

This [link](https://tedvinke.wordpress.com/2014/02/13/mockito-why-you-should-not-use-injectmocks-annotation-to-autowire-fields/) helped me in identifying how to work on `@Autowired` objects which is not visible

Answer (score 1):

One thing to take into account is if you have a non-empty constructor in your class you must call MockitoAnnotations.initMocks in your test class because InjectMocks annotation will not work, for example:

```
public class classA {

  @Autowired
  private ClassB classB;

  private Integer i;

  public ClassA(Integer i) {
    this.i = i;
  }

}
```

Mockito will try to use that constructor and injection of mocks will fail using InjectMocks annotation, so you will need to call initMocks method instead, not sure if is a bug but this solved the problem for me.

Comment: This answer worked for me. Thank you! Another important thing you have to take into account whilst testing classes, _which inherit another one_, is a possible constructor inside the parent-class. Mockito will then use this "abstract constructor (?)" instead of the injection strategy provided in the sub-class; Thus possibly resulting in a null value for the mock.