# Mocking two maps in a class

Tags: java, maps, mockito

I have to test a class that injects two maps with springs.
I would like to mock both maps.
I use the Mock notation as follows :

```
@Mock
private Map<String, Integer> map1;

@Mock
private Map<String, Date> map2;
```

but I get the following error :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.util.Date
```

It seems that only the first mocked map is used for both maps.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Works for me. Mockito ver 1.10.19. Is there something you're not showing us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the type of the two fields are the same, `mockito` doesn't know to how to inject your mock by types. So it tries to inject it by name. In this case, looks like the name of fields in your class under test does not match to the mock object that you have created.
Here is the [doc](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.11.0/org/mockito/InjectMocks.html) for `@InjectMocks`:

> Field injection; mocks will first be resolved by type (if a single
>   type match injection will happen regardless of the name), then, if
>   there is several property of the same type, by the match of the field
>   name and the mock name.

You can either rename your filed or use explicit mock names:

```
@Mock(name="foo")
private Map<String, Integer> map1;

@Mock(name="bar")
private Map<String, Date> map2;
```

But I don't think that this is the best solution. In case if the filed name will be renamed you will got the false negative test result: functionality works correct but test fails.

For me, the best solution is to refactor your code so the class under test receive the dependencies in the constructor. After that you can mock it like this:

```
@Mock
private Map<String, Integer> map1;

@Mock
private Map<String, Date> map2;

private ClassUnderTets cut;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    cut = new ClassUnderTets(map1, map2);
}
```

Or even:

```
@Mock
private Map<String, Integer> map1;

@Mock
private Map<String, Date> map2;

@InjectMocks
private ClassUnderTets cut;
```

As mentioned in the docs:

> Constructor injection; the biggest constructor is chosen, then arguments are resolved with
>   mocks declared in the test only

Comment: Thank you for the help, I was already using the InjectMocks notation but it did not work. When I replaced it with the dependencies in the constructor, it worked

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have problem because you try to inject two mocks with the same interface (variable names does not match to properties for example)

Please take a look at second post from this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21054057/how-to-inject-multiple-mocks-of-the-same-interface) for reference.

> Property setter injection; mocks will first be resolved by type, then,
>   if there is several property of the same type, by the match of the
>   property name and the mock name.

Comment: I injected the maps with the constructor instead of using the "InjectMocks" notation like is recommanded on the second post and it worked.
I don't really understand why InjectMocks does not work in my case.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
@Mock
private Map map1;

@Mock
private Map map2;
```

instead

```
@Mock
private Map<String, Integer> map1;

@Mock
private Map<String, Date> map2;
```

Then you will just need to mock a behavior like:

```
when(map1).get("hello").thenReturn(25);
when(map2).get("birthday").thenReturn(new Date(2000, 07, 24));
```