# Can't use 2 Mocks from the same class with different diamond operator classes

Tags: java, spring, mockito

I have the following classes structure.

```
public interface Foo<T extends Bar>{
   Optional<T> find();
}

public class A extends Bar{}

public class B extends Bar{}

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class C{
  Foo<A> a;
  Foo<B> b;

  B bInstance = b.find();
}

public class CTest{
   @Mock
   Foo<A> a;

   @Mock
   Foo<B> b;

   @InjectMocks
   C c;

   @Test
   public void testSomething(){
      when(a.someMethod()).thenReturn(someVariable);
      when(b.someMethod()).thenReturn(someOtherVariable);
   }
}
```

Then maybe I have some code in class C like:

```
B bInstance = b.find();
```

And the problem here is that when find is called, it returns a new instance from class A instead of B, i.e. the variable from the mock a instead of mock b. Therefore, I get a ClassLoadException doing some work afterwards.

Is this supposed to work as expected or is it a problem caused by mocking 2 variables from the same class (Foo) of 2 different diamond operator classes (how is this called?) (A and B) that Mockito can't interprete?
Am I missing something else here?
This may not be enough information to do the follow-up but hopefully there is some concept misunderstanding that I have and can be fixed easily.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create test subject myself then

```
public class CTest{
   @Mock
   Foo<A> a;

   @Mock
   Foo<B> b;

// @InjectMocks  since it is not working for you, lets skip it
   C service;

   @Before
   public void setup(){
       service=new C(a,b);
   }

   @Test
   public void testSomething(){
      when(a.someMethod()).thenReturn(someVariable);
      when(b.someMethod()).thenReturn(someOtherVariable);
   }
}
```

Comment: What would this change? instead of using the @InjectMocks annotation

Comment: It would do exactly that. And would fix your issue.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, it's working now. I don't know exactly what's the difference. Could you provide with an explaination?

Comment: Is this a Mockito bug? @InjectMocks annotation can't differentiate between 2 classes that are the same with different diamond operators so using a constructor works?

Comment: I would say this is due to type erasure. With inject mocks mockito has to "figure out" which mock fits which constructor arguments - probably a is used for for both. I didnt check the implementation

Comment: You might be able to use @Mock(name) and @Qualifier. https://stackoverflow.com/a/21054354/1527544